# How to control or initialize children thread properties from parent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the need to control creation of new threads, so they always have some caracteriscs of the main thead. In order to do this I'm using a class ThreadFactory where I set CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture.

```
public static class ThreadFactory {
    public static Thread Create(ThreadStart start) {
        var thread = new Thread(start);
        thread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        thread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        return thread;
    }
}
```

For example, if I want to create a new thread it is going to be initiazed with CurrentCulture equals the windows settings, let's say english. In case I have changed the main thread to spanish, the new thread is still going to be english. Because of this behavior I always use the ThreadFactory to create new threads this way:

```
Thread t1 = ThreadFactory.Create(() => {
    //Thread code
});
t1.start();
```

Doing this I'm sure that new threads are always started with the same culture as the main thread and don't need to change this in every thread code.
The problem is that I would like to have one more property that worked the same way as CurrentCulture. 
I tried using ThreadStatic attribute, but it initializes to a null value in the child thread. And using it as static property is not possible, because I need it to be thread safe for the main thread.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "one more property that worked the same way?" To split hairs, the class has no properties so it can't have one *more* property. (It has a method.) What prevents adding another method?

Comment: This question is unclear. What "one more property" are you trying to set? What _specific_ problem are you having trying to set it? As far as the code you showed, if you want to copy the culture values from the current thread, that a) assumes that the current thread's default settings have been changed (which is fine, but uncommon), and b) makes me wonder what you want to do in the new threads if the main thread's culture settings change. Maybe the latter is not relevant to this question (though not being able to understand the question, it's impossible to know), but it's worth thinking about.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. What I want to do is expose a property of the child thread so the parent can change it, like I do with the CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question long time ago, then I found this, you can put everything you want in that thread :

```
private static void CreateThread()
{
  var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
  var currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
  var thread = new Thread(() =>
  {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUICulture;

    // Do something here, example:
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

  }) {IsBackground = true};
  thread.Start();
}
```